# “binutils”/Kernel 6.5.X - “Invalid –compress-debug-sections option: `zstd’”

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, kernel-parameters

I'm trying to build a driver for a USB to HDMI adapter...

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 534d:6021 MacroSilicon VGA Display Adapter
```

**NOTE:** "lsusb" output.

... but this error is occurring...

```
Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: `zstd'
```

...as can be seen in the full output below...

```
[eduardolac@eduardolac-pc ms912x]$ make all -j
make CHECK="/usr/bin/sparse" -C /lib/modules/6.5.5-1-MANJARO/build M=/home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.5.5-1-MANJARO/build'
  CC [M]  /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_registers.o
  CC [M]  /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_connector.o
  CC [M]  /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_transfer.o
  CC [M]  /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_drv.o
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: `zstd'
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_connector.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: `zstd'
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_registers.o] Error 1
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: `zstd'
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_transfer.o] Error 1
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: `zstd'
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:243: /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x/ms912x_drv.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/usr/lib/modules/6.5.5-1-MANJARO/build/Makefile:2034: /home/eduardolac/Data1/Temp/20231016.1224.0/ms912x] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/lib/modules/6.5.5-1-MANJARO/build'
make: *** [Makefile:15: modules] Error 2
```

The "ld" available on my system does not support the "zstd" option for the "compress-debug-sections" parameter...

```
[eduardolac@eduardolac-pc ms912x]$ ld --help | grep "compress-debug-sections"
  --compress-debug-sections=[none|zlib|zlib-gnu|zlib-gabi]
```

... but the "binutils" package (which contains "ld") that I have installed on my OS is version 2.41-3, which according to this documentation
( https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils.html ) already supports the "zstd" option for the "compress-debug-sections" parameter.

The Kernel I have installed is 6.5.X .

Please help me with this.

**Thanks!**

---

**Further...**

https://askubuntu.com/a/1488791/134723
https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x/issues/5
https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x

Comment: `ld` 2.41 supports zstd compression if it was built with the right library. Which distribution are you using?

Comment: Greetings @StephenKitt ! I'm using Manjaro Linux (an Arch Linux-based distribution). 

Comment: ah I take that back, the module sources don't seem to do cause any zstd to be used, so it is a bug in Manjaro's toolchain

Comment: Greetings @MarcusMüller ! Any ideas how I can resolve this? 

Comment: no, sadly not. The Makefile looks OK, and unless you know you installed some third-party `ld`, then my guess really is that there's not much you can do but rebuild manjaro's binaries toolchain to enable that flag, and it's not clear to me how that would happen, because they would use the same to build the stock kernel modules. Does it work in a clean container?

Comment: @MarcusMüller When you say `Does it work in a clean container?`, do you mean just compiling for testing purposes or compiling and bringing the binaries to the host?

Comment: start with compiling. But honestly, if that works, I wouldn't know why you wouldn't use the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the "ld" binary used in my case, for some reason, was provided by "Homebrew"...

```
[eduardolac@eduardolac-pc ms912x]$ pacman -Qo ld
error: No package owns /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/ld
```

So the solution, for me, was to remove "Homebrew", as I wasn't using it for anything...

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

And as a precaution I reinstalled binutils...

```
yay -Rdd binutils
yay -S binutils
```

So finally, just open and close the terminal and voilà...

```
[eduardolac@eduardolac-pc ~]$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.41.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

**Thanks!**

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722984/3223785 ]

Comment: Seeing that you've installed some other package manager who was free to pollute your system with its own programs: I think it would be wise to do this on a clean, fresh installation of Arch. You basically made yourself and multiple experts scratch their heads for a prolonged amount of time because you've had a modified system, and I don't think that's wise.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm trying to understand what you contributed with this comment. 

Comment: I'm saying: Do yourself a favor and reproduce the issue on a clean installation. your system has too many unknowns, as this answer illustrates :) You might be digging into issues that come from that, which simply don't exist on other systems.